# Using a java method in select query jooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have a mysql query which is in the following format

```
        dslContext
            .select(
                ITEMDATA.ITEMID,
                ITEMDATA.COST,
                ITEMNAMES.ITEMNAME
            )
            .from(ITEMDATA)
            .join(ITEMNAMES)
            .on(ITEMDATA.ITEMID=ITEMNAMES.ITEMID)
            .where(conditions);
```

The above query joins ITEMDATA with ITEMNAMES table to select ITEMNAME in the result. I am caching ITEMNAMES table in-memory and want to avoid the join with ITEMNAMES table. This would speed up the query and would simplify the query since the actual query is much more complex.

I would like to use it something similar to the following. I want to call itemNamesCache.getItemName in the select params list which gives the ITEMNAME and returns a part of the select result. `getItemName` should take the ITEMID returned in the response as a parameter and give the ITEMNAME.

```
    dslContext.
        select(
            ITEMDATA.ITEMID,
            ITEMDATA.COST,
            itemNamesCache.getItemName(valueOfItemId)
        )
        .from(ITEMDATA)
        .where(conditions);
```

P.S: I can iterate the results and call the itemNamesCache.getItemName. But I would like to use something embedded in the query if it's possible

Comment: Note: `ITEMDATA.ITEMID=ITEMNAMES.ITEMID` that doesn't really work. You might want to use the `eq()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a callback from a SQL query back into some Java logic, even if the fact that you're constructing the SQL query with jOOQ (and thus Java) makes it look like that were feasible.

However, you could post-process the jOOQ result by patching records using a previously built cache:

#### A Java solution

In case you're working with a database that really can't handle this simple join (and you've checked that you have all proper indexes and constraints in place!) then you could try the following solution:

```java
// Assuming this import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

write...

```java
Map<Integer, String> itemNamesCache =
dslContext.selectDistinct(ITEMNAMES.ITEMID, ITEMNAMES.NAME)
          .from(ITEMNAMES)
          .fetchMap(ITEMNAMES.ITEMID, ITEMNAMES.NAME);

dslContext
    .select(
        ITEMDATA.ITEMID,
        ITEMDATA.COST,
        // create an empty column here
        inline(null, String.class).as(ITEMNAMES.NAME))
    .from(ITEMDATA)
    .where(conditions)
    // fill the empty column with cached values
    .fetch(r -> r.value3(itemNamesCache.get(r.value1())));
```

#### A SQL-based solution

The SQL way to do that would be to write a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

```sql
SELECT
  itemdata.itemid,
  itemdata.cost,
  (SELECT itemnames.name FROM itemnames WHERE itemnames.itemid = itemdata.itemid)
FROM 
  itemdata
WHERE
  ...
```

#### With jOOQ

```java
// Assuming this import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

... write:

```java
dslContext
    .select(
        ITEMDATA.ITEMID,
        ITEMDATA.COST,
        field(select(ITEMNAMES.NAME)
           .from(ITEMNAMES)
           .where(ITEMDATA.ITEMID.eq(ITEMNAMES.ITEMID)))
        .as(ITEMNAMES.NAME)
    )
    .from(ITEMDATA)
    .where(conditions)
    .fetch();
```

In theory, both queries should run at exactly the same speed, because they're equivalent (if you have a foreign key on `ITEMDATA.ITEMID`).

In practice, most databases will probably have better performance for the `JOIN` query, unless they implement scalar subquery caching (e.g. like Oracle), which can drastically speed up the second query, depending on the number of distinct `ITEMIDs` (the smaller, the better).

Comment: Of course I can do a join. But the actual query is much more complicated which involves 5 tables. First reason is to simplify the query. The second one is query performance. Will the performance not increase if I avoid a join?

Comment: 5 joins is not a complex query :) And it's not a hard query for most databases. Just try it and measure it, and you'll see that the join solution is probably the fastest.

Comment: I have made a single join and measured the time taken by executing the queries on the db server directly (ignoring the java layer latency). Without the join, the query took 0.26 sec and with the join it took 0.58 sec.

Comment: Do you have all the required indexes? Have you run the query several times to avoid any measurement errors? Have you compared the solution with my correlated subquery alternative?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have all the required indexes in place and ran it several times. The join takes more time. The subquery takes almost the exact same time with a 0.01 sec difference.